# Extract Date from text file

Tags: string, file, date, text, extract

We have to identify and extract the date from given samplese

```
Oct  4 07:44:45  cli[1290]: PAPI_Send: To: 7f000001:8372 Type:0x4 Timed out. 

Oct  4 08:16:01  webui[1278]: USER:admin@192.168.100.205 COMMAND:<wlan ssid-profile "MFI-SSID" > -- command executed successfully 

Oct  4 08:16:01  webui[1278]: USER:admin@192.168.100.205 COMMAND:<wlan ssid-profile "MFI-SSID" opmode opensystem > -- command executed successfully
```

Here the main problem is, Date format is versatile. it may be "oct 4 2004" or "oct/04/2004" etc

Comment: What language? Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Write a script that would filter all the data variables?

Comment: @Polynomial... language is java , not exactly a homework , its just a part of an other simple project. i have done to identify the dates when i know format of that date, i have to check all the date format to find out is it date or not,

in my project, i have to store the general word,IPs and date seperately. I did for others but stuck at date identification, because it contains spaces, so their is probability Oct ( in above example) may be treated as general string.

so can you suggest me how can i identify that "Oct 4 07:44:45" is exact a date ?

Comment: @AaronLee .. i did it, in this case date "Oct 4" is treated as separate data and its difficult to identify them as a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parsing is best way to handle such a problems. 
so learn about parsing techniques then use them on your project and enjoy. [Appropriate design pattern for an event log parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94148/appropriate-design-pattern-for-an-event-log-parser)